# android listview item style?

Tags: android, listview, styles

before i posted this thread , I've googled ( how to style listview items ) i cannot find a good example to showing how to style listview item ( normal , touch , long click etc ) background colors also i want to do like this VK listview with border radius and box shadow , please i really need this help also other people searching for this is there any example or can some one tell me what i have to put inside the xml selector background of the item ?

image one show how to listview item has border radius and shadow

[image]

image 2 showing when i click on the item

[image]

so guys is there any way to do like this ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, it's best to use styles here:

```
<!-- res/values/styles.xml -->
<style name="ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_item_selector</item>
</style>
```

The `@color/light_grey` definition:

```
<!--- res/values/colors.xml --->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="light_grey">#cccccc</color>
</resources>
```

You'll have to define the `light_grey` color in your `colors.xml` and create the card style `list_item_selector.xml` in your drawables folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"/> 
</selector>
```

Comment: inside `selector` you are using `drawable` to set backgrounds but i need to set background colors like `#ffffff` how ?

Comment: Because you're looking at a card style with a shadow, you'll have to use a 9-patch drawable or else the selector will extend to the edge of each list item, which would look ugly.

Comment: @Krylez how to set that to `listView` this code : `style="@style/ListView"` not working

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to override your value in your AppTheme in the styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:listSelector">@color/teal_100</item>
</style>
```

This overriding reflects on all your ListViews which you are using in your app.

You may also use drawable instead of color.